# Linux Command to revive process

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, unix

Is there a Unix command that monitors arbitrary processes and revive those processes if they got killed by the OS? For example, I have a background daemon that executes periodically but sometimes it would get killed by the OS. I'd like to either revive either that process again or something similar.

Comment: check https://immortal.run A *nix cross-platform (OS agnostic) supervisor

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions on server-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [unix.se]

Answer (score 2):

Given the vague nature of this question and what the OP has tried, here is an answer. A recent Ubuntu (assumes from the tag), OP uses a `systemd` system, and in this kinda system, one could write a `systemd` service script that would restart the daemon if it exits;

```
~]# cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/myawesome.service
 [Unit]
 Description=My Awesome Service
 After=systemd-logind.service

 [Service]
 Type=notify
 ExecStart=/path/to/my/awesome/daemon
 KillMode=process
 Restart=always

 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then start this service,

```
 ~]# systemctl start myawesome.service
 ~]# systemctl enable myawesome.service # To sustain after a reboot
```

To know more about systemd service unit files, follow this links:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html
   https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html